# DJS v14 How to count every embed message it's been sent?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I would like to make it count on every embed sent to a text channel with +1?
For example a user writes to a text channel. BOT is gonna take that message, delete it and post it by tagging him and count the embed as number #1 etc..
Thanks in advance!!

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const v10_1 = require("discord-api-types/v10");
const discord_js_1 = require("discord.js");
const Events_1 = require("../../structures/Events");
exports.default = new Events_1.Event("messageCreate", async (message) => {
    try {
        if (message.author.bot)
            return;
        if (message.channelId !== process.env.reviewsChannelId)
            return;
        if (message.channel.type !== v10_1.ChannelType.GuildNewsThread &&
            message.channel.type !== v10_1.ChannelType.GuildText)
            return;
        const content = message?.content;
        if (!content)
            return await message.delete();
        const reviews = new discord_js_1.EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle(`[ <:review:1005784096120782888> ] - Review - [ <:review:1005784096120782888> ]`)
            .setColor(`#fdaf17`)
            .setDescription(`**${content}**`)
            .setTimestamp();
        await message.channel.send({ embeds: [reviews] });
        await message.delete();
    }
    catch (error) {
        return console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 choices, a simple variable like

```js
let count = 1;
```

and after each `await message.channel.send({ embeds: [reviews] });` you add a line with `count++;`

and in the embed you write by example `.setFooter({text: "Embed #" + count})`

But the problem of this solution is if your bot restart, you'll loose the actual embed count.

So you can do the same way but instead of a simple variable, use a json file to store the variable or a database.

Hope this can helps you !

Comment: how can i store it in the db? i have db for my bot